# UWP/WinRT: On the CommandBar overflow menu, why is there ugly blank space on the bottom?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to use the CommandBar class, but it isn't behaving.

Here is the XAML for my trivial test:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="NewWindow"></AppBarButton>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="Secondary Button"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Grid>
```

However, when I press the `...` overflow button on the CommandBar to expose the overflow menu, for whatever reason there is an ugly extra blank chin on the bottom of the overflow menu, making the whole thing look rather unprofessional. Here is a screenshot of the problem, with the blank space underneath the `Secondary Button` being the problematic part.

[image: Extra space on overflow menu]

When testing on a first-party Universal Windows Platform app like the Edge browser, there is no such chin on the dropdown. For what it's worth, though, I suspect that Edge is using a custom version of the CommandBar, as I don't think there is any way to avoid the CommandBar extending downwards when you tap the `...` overflow button, or to insert icon buttons into the dropdown menu like used for the Zoom buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the default style of the CommandBar.
You can remove that blank space by editing a copy of the `CommandBarOverflowPresenter` template and removing the bottom margin on the ItemsPresenter. Here is the resulting style:

```
<Style TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource CommandBarOverflowMaxWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ScrollViewer AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="0"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is there a good tutorial on how to generate this type of template? Particularly, how did you know what needed to be filled in for the hierarchy of the structure and all of those default values that weren't directly related to the margin?

Comment: It's very easy: open the page in Designer mode, right click the element you want to template then Edit style -> Edit a copy.

Comment: Is there a way to do "Edit a copy" of the template on an item that is difficult to select in Designer mode? For example, the header of a PivotItem that is populated with data binding, such that it doesn't appear in Designer mode at all?

Comment: Probably with design-time data. Otherwise, you can find the default templates on the web (MSDN).

Comment: You can also find all the default templates in the generic.xaml file on your own filesystem. Look in the installationfolder of Windows Kits. Its default is: `C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml`

Answer (score 1):

While [Olivier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33009488/6240567) does cover how to remove the space below the `CommandBar` when the overflow menu is open (and does it well) - it doesn't explain the reasoning behind the "blank space" in the first place.

I thought I would add an answer to give a bit of weight as to the use of that "blank space", for future visitors to this question.

The purpose of the overflow button `...` is dual-purpose. I'll explain below.

---

#### 1 - Avoid Ambiguity

The overflow button `...` icon provides a way for the user to view the `Label`s for the `PrimaryCommands` (the ones along the main strip of the `CommandBar`).

This proves very useful in the case that some of the icons may not be immediately obvious as to what they might mean.

For example:

## ×

Could mean either "Cancel", "No", "Delete" etc.

We can add `Label="Delete"` to the `AppBarButton` in order to distinguish that this button is to "Delete" an item or whatever.

If the user were to wish to find out what the icons for the buttons mean/represent, they could simply tap the `...` to show the labels for the buttons.

*In your screenshot, because your `PrimaryCommands` don't have any labels, there is just the whitespace displayed.*

Here's an example of how we can use the `Label` in order to understand what the buttons mean:

```
<CommandBar>
    <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Stop" Label="Stop" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Next" />
    </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="Like" />
        <AppBarButton Label="Dislike" />
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

The above code could be used to create a playback control bar for a media app:

[image: commandbar in uwp]

When the user presses the `...` button, the labels are then displayed clearly underneath each button - in order to see what they are intended for.

[image: commandbar in uwp]

This kind of UI behaviour has been around since at least Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight), albeit with possibly different markup. *I could be wrong - it could have been sooner - feel free to correct me*

#### 2 - Display SecondaryCommands

In addition to the above useful design feature (and as is obvious from the original question) - the `...` overflow button can be pressed to show the `SecondaryCommands`.

It pops them out into view using the `CommandBarOverflowPresenter` that is defined.

This is more useful for "less important" actions that the user might wish to take. For example "Leave Feedback", "Download" - or whatever the designer might deem as not-so-important.

As per the sample above, the "Like" and "Dislike" buttons are not of utmost importance to the user in order to use the `CommandBar` effectively:

[image: commandbar in uwp]

---

I hope this adds a bit of insight into how the `CommandBar` can be used to aid and enhance user experience in a UWP/WinRT/Silverlight app, in line with the currently accepted answer which shows how to remove the whitespace in the original question.